# ignore verifying SSL certificates python sockets

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, ssl

How do i ignore verifying ssl certificates using python sockets when i run main.py on some random ips it dosen't respond with anything and on other random ips it works perfectly
how can i do something equivalent to **requests.get('https://51.83.254.xxx/', verify=False)**.

**main.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#coding:utf-8

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from termcolor import colored
import concurrent.futures
import argparse
import socket
import json
import ssl
import sys

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument("-f", "--file", help = "<inputfilename>: Input from list of hosts")
parser.add_argument("-p", "--port", help = "The port to which you want to receive a response from")
parser.add_argument("-w", "--workers", help = "The number of threads you want to use", default='5')
if len(sys.argv)==1:
    parser.print_help()
    sys.exit(1)

args = parser.parse_args()


IP = open(args.file)
IP = [x.strip('\n') for x in IP.readlines()]
port = int(args.port)
workers = int(args.workers)


def HTTPS(IP):
    try:
        context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS)
        context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE
        ssock = context.wrap_socket(socket.socket())
        socket.setdefaulttimeout(0.5)
        ssock.connect((IP, port))
        hostname = socket.getfqdn(IP)
        request = ("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: " + IP + "\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0\r\nAccept: */*\r\n\r\n").encode('utf-8')
        ssock.sendall(request)
        while True:
            response = ssock.recv(2048).decode('utf-8')
            if ( len(response) < 1 ):
                break
            (headers, body) = response.split("\r\n\r\n")
            soup = BeautifulSoup(body, 'html.parser')
            if hostname == IP:
                print(colored(IP, 'green'), colored(port, 'yellow'), colored(soup.title.string, 'blue'),  json.dumps(headers))
            else:
                print(colored(IP, 'green'), colored(port, 'yellow'), colored(hostname, 'magenta'), colored(soup.title.string, 'blue'), json.dumps(headers))
        ssock.close()
    except (socket.timeout, socket.error, ssl.SSLError):
        pass


with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=workers) as executor:
    executor.map(HTTPS, IP)
```

Comment: "i ignore verifying ssl certificates" Why? Doing so makes TLS almost useless, you could as well just use direct HTTP. If you can not authenticate the remote party, even if you send the content encrypted you have no idea really who you are sending it to so you can as well send it in clear. Said differently: never do that.

Comment: Also, you should use the relevant Python library to do HTTP calls instead of trying to generate the strings by hand yourself as you are guaranteed to fall into many traps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you provide no details at all about the actual errors which happen. It looks even like you are not interested in these errors at all because you simple `pass` on many kind of errors.  But very likely your problems are not caused by SSL verification in the first place. To name a few of the several problems which can happen in your code and which you simply ignore:

- SSL handshake fails because the server requires the SNI extension (i.e. target hostname) but you don't provide any. This will be a very common error.
- SSL handshake fails because there is no shared cipher or no shared protocol version.
- SSL handshake fails because the server requires a client certificate.
- And of course it might happen that already the TCP connection fails to the given IP:port.

None of these problems can be solved by disabling certificate validation.